# Need to choose documents from mobile storage Wechat applet

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

We want to choose files (pdf, png, doc, ppt etc...) from our mobile device and upload it to a third party. We tried wx.chooseMedia, but it only supports images and videos, as well as wx.chooseMessageFile, which lets users choose files from their chat history.

Is there a way to choose documents from the mobile storage (iOS or Android)?

Comment: I developed similar functions about it.At least, we leave a link which can be copyed for user and guide them open in browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should kown more about the rules of IOS.
IOS don't support upload common file from mobile disk.
So all applications can't provide solutions with uploading file.
The api "wx.chooseMessageFile" only provide limited method to do this.

Comment: I developed similar functions about it.At least, we leave a link which can be copyed for user and guide them open in browser